# VirtualBox Battle.net error

Tags: virtualbox, vmware

I recently installed windows 7 on VirtualBox and installed battle.net.
When I start battle.net I get this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LfGK.png
I googled a lot but I was not able to find an anwser :/

Also tried to put Windows 7 on VMWare but that resulted in me getting the same error.

Before this I tried downloading the driver for the GPU I have but then I get this error, https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cyyr.png

Hope you guys can help me :)

Answer (score 3):

You may need to enable 3D acceleration on VirtualBox. By default it is disabled.

The steps to enable:

1. Right click the Windows 7 VM in Virtual Box and click **Settings**.
2. Click the **Display** category.
3. Check **Enable 3D Acceleration** and increase **Video Memory** as needed.
4. Install drivers:

   1. While the VM is running, click **Devices** menu and then **Install Guest Additions**
   2. Click **Run VBoxWindowsAdditions.exe** in the popup and run through the installer.

See: http://www.howtogeek.com/124479/how-to-enable-3d-acceleration-and-use-windows-aero-in-virtualbox/ for extra information.

Note that the article states the 3D acceleration is experimental and should run older games, but possibly not newer games.  The article was written in 2012, so I'm not sure what the current state is.  You should be able to tell if it's enabled by whether or not the Aero interface is usable.